# Grant privileges on future tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3.1. I have `test` database and `backup` user which is used to backup the database. I have no problems with granting privileges to all current tables, but I have to grant privileges each time the new table is added to schema.

```
createdb test

psql test
test=# create table foo();
CREATE TABLE
test=# grant all on all tables in schema public to backup;
GRANT
test=# create table bar();
CREATE TABLE

psql -U backup test
test=> select * from foo;
test=> select * from bar;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation bar
```

Is it possible to grant access to tables which will be created in future without making user owner of the table?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to alter default privileges for `backup` user:

```
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to backup;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to backup;
```

From the comment by Matt Schaffer:

> As caveat, the default only applies to the user that executed the
> `alter` statement. This confused me since I was driving most of my
> permissions statements from the postgres user but creating tables from
> an app user. In short, you might need something like this depending on
> your setup:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER webapp IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO backup;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER webapp IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;
```

Where `webapp` is the user that will be creating new tables in the future and `backup` is the user that will be able to read from new tables created by `webapp`.

Comment: Relevant documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: As caveat, the default only applies to the user that executed the alter statement.

This confused me since I was driving most of my permissions statements from the postgres user but creating tables from an app user.

In short, you might need something like this depending on your setup:

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER webapp IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO backup;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER webapp IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;`

Comment: It's confusing to me how the limits of alter default privileges are documented. Am I correct that this answer does not actually work if backup is not a member of the role that owns the table? It's not working for me when I try to `alter default privileges in schema public grant SELECT on tables to backup`, when my backup user is not an owner or superuser and has no other permissions.

Comment: I have a superuser and a read-only.  This doesn't work for me when I add a new table and then try to SELECT from the read-only.  I have to re-run the GRANT SELECT ON... statement every time I add a table.

Comment: @danny No, the answer only works as-is if the alter statements are executed as the user/role who creates the tables. That means if they are executed by - say - juser and only juser creates new tables then everything works fine. If other users (e.g. user postgres) create tables in that database/schema then these defaults aren't applied to those tables then.

Comment: @JPDuffy how are your users called? It should work if your super-user executes the ALTER statements and if it's also the same user who creates the tables. Otherwise you have to add a FOR ROLE rule like this `FOR ROLE user_who_creates_the_tables` . You can check the existing default privileges with `\ddp` from `psql` - check there if the `owner` column `/usersuffix` matches the user who creates the tables.

Comment: I have 1. `adminuser`, 2. `tableuser`, 3. `readuser`. What kind of fancy line do I have to write so the permission is given from the `adminuser`, table is created from `tableuser`, and readonly permissions on `readuser`?

Comment: @Esqarrouth
`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER tableuser IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readuser;`

Comment: @Esqarrouth for tables created prior to executing `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER tableuser IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readuser;` the permissions will not get propagated so `readuser` cannot access them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **backup** user to have access to the **future** tables of user**N**,
you must run the code below under each user**N** who creates new tables,
because ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...
works only for objects **by that user under whom you run** ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO backup;
```

Comment: [@Andrey Chernih's answer from eight years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22684537/3025856) already proposes that exact change.

Comment: For accuracy, @JeremyCaney, I note that the "exact change" proposed by Denis was only added 2 years ago, not the 8 years of the original question, from the comment by Mat Schaffer, albeit still older than Denis's answer, just not by 8 years.

Comment: @JeremyCaney From that answer, it was not clear to me that you have to run the code under the user who creates the tables, or under postgres but with the "FOR USER" clause. Denis' answer helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to create a role, grant connect access to the role and then alter default privileges to keep access for future objects. However, it seems that the below command doesn't work at role level.
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to backup;

I followed the below documentation but seems that there are two command do not work for roles.
DOC: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/
First command:
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydatabase TO readonly;
Second command:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO readonly;
(For ROLES usually it needs TO ROLE, I also tried TO ROLE but still doesn't work.