# Is there a way to grant permissions on tables that don't exist yet (or that get recreated)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database with a read-only role set up; let's call it 'app_user_ro'. I am using a third party data loading tool (running as 'app_user') that drops and recreates the tables. After recreating the tables, the previous permissions are gone and 'app_user_ro' can no longer select from the tables.

I am using Postgres 11.3 running on Ubuntu 19.04. I've looked at [Grant privileges on future tables in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684255/grant-privileges-on-future-tables-in-postgresql) and tried altering the default privileges but still 'app_user_ro' can't read data from the tables after they are dropped and recreated.

I've tried:

```sql
-- The accepted answer
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app_user_ro;

-- An alternative answer from the comments:
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER app_user_ro IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app_user_ro;
```

The only thing that works is manually granting the permissions after each import:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO app_user_ro;
```

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) state:

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of

The roles I had were:

```sql
app_data_loader=# \du
                                      List of roles
   Role name    |                         Attributes                         | Member of  
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 app_user       |                                                            | {postgres}
 app_user_ro    |                                                            | {}
 pg             | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Originally I was running the `ALTER DEFAULT...` commands as the 'postgres' role but more recently I added the 'app_user_ro' role to the 'app_user' role (the one loading the data) and tried running it as the 'app_user' role with no change in behaviour.

For now I'll just schedule a job to grant the permissions after each import but it seems like there should be a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The puzzle piece you are missing is that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects tables that get **created** by the role specified in the `FOR USER/ROLE` clause (or, if you omit that, by the user who ran the statement).

So if it is `app_user` that creates the tables, you'll have to run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_user ...;
```

Comment: Sometimes I was logging in as `postgres`, other times as `app_user`. If I'd happened to run the unmodified command as `app_user` it would have worked but I would have had no real understanding why. Thanks for the clear explanation!