# Grant privileges on future objects in Unity Catalog

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

Similar to this question : [Grant privileges on future tables in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684255/grant-privileges-on-future-tables-in-postgresql)

I would like to enable SELECT access to all the tables that will be created within an existing database, is there any way to achieve this with Unity Catalog ?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality isn't available yet (as of end of August 2022nd). But it should be available later this year (no confirmation for the timeline yet).

Update Jan 2023rd: This functionality [was released in October 2022nd](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/product/2022/october.html#privilege-inheritance-in-now-supported-in-unity-catalog).